# How to merge cells and remove blank spaces in my DataGrid using proper loop

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, loops, datagrid

My title is still broad so i'll explain here further.
This is my current output using my code:

[image]
.

But I want to make it look like this.[image].

As you can see on the pictures, i want to remove the blank spaces. Because if I selected MORE data, let's say I selected 7 more days, it will go DIAGONALLY not horizontally.

I think I have a problem regarding my loops. Hope you can help me trace because I've been stuck here for a week debugging. (nevermind my long query, i just want to post all my code. I've also added comments for easier debugging.)

Here's my code:

```
  Private Sub LoadDateAndUser()

    Dim SqlStr As String = ""
    Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection(DataSource.ConnectionString)
    Dim sqlComm As New SqlCommand(SqlStr, sqlConn)
    Dim sqlAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlComm)
    Dim o_Dataset As New DataSet()

    SqlStr = " SELECT    convert(varchar(10), A.TransDate, 101)   as TransDate,ADMMED.TransNum, ADMMED.AdministeredDate, D.Dosage [Dosage], ISNULL(C.GenericName, ' ') + ' (' + IsNull(B.ItemName,'') + ' ' + IsNull(B.ItemDesc,'') + ')' [Medication], ADMMED.UserID" & _
             " FROM INVENTORY..tbInvStockCard as A" & _
             " LEFT OUTER JOIN INVENTORY..tbInvMaster as B On A.ItemID = B.ItemID  " & _
             " LEFT OUTER JOIN Inventory.dbo.tbForGeneric as C On B.GenericID = C.GenericID" & _
             " LEFT OUTER JOIN  Station..tbNurse_AdministeredMedicines ADMMED on  a.idnum= ADMMED.idnum " & _
             " LEFT OUTER JOIN build_file.dbo.tbCoDosage as D on A.DosageID = D.DosageID" & _
             "  LEFT OUTER JOIN Station.dbo.tbNurseCommunicationFile as E on A.IdNum = E.IDnum  and E.ReferenceNum = A.RefNum" & _
             " WHERE A.IdNum = '" & Session.Item("IDNum") & "' and ( A.RevenueID = 'PH' or A.RevenueID = 'PC' ) " & _
             " AND A.LocationID = '20' and Not IsNull(ADMMED.AdministeredDate, '') = ''" & _
             " AND A.RefNum = ADMMED.ReferenceNum and ADMMED.ItemID = A.itemid" & _
             " AND (B.ItemClassificationID = '1' or  B.ItemClassificationID = '10' or  B.ItemClassificationID = '11' or  B.ItemClassificationID = '16' or  B.ItemClassificationID = '2' or  B.ItemClassificationID = '9')" & _
             " order by TransDate desc,ADMMED.AdministeredDate desc"

    sqlComm.CommandText = SqlStr
    sqlAdapter.Fill(o_Dataset, "Table")

    Dim o_Row As DataRow
    Dim o_AdmDates As New Collection()
    Dim s_FormattedLastAdmDate As String = ""
    Dim s_FormattedAdmDate As String = ""
    Dim o_DerivedTable As New DataTable()

    With o_DerivedTable
        .Columns.Add("TransDate")
        .Columns.Add("Medication")
        .Columns.Add("Dosage")
        .Columns.Add("TransNum")
    End With

    'Select all unformatted administered dates from the query
    Dim o_UnformattedAdmDates As DataRow() = o_Dataset.Tables(0).Select("", "AdministeredDate Desc")

    'Extract distinct  administered dates and change its format
    For Each o_Row In o_UnformattedAdmDates
        s_FormattedAdmDate = Format(CDate(o_Row.Item("AdministeredDate")), KC_Date_Format) 'eg. Jan 01 15 
        If s_FormattedLastAdmDate <> s_FormattedAdmDate Then
            s_FormattedLastAdmDate = s_FormattedAdmDate
            o_AdmDates.Add(s_FormattedLastAdmDate) 'add all formatted dates in o_AdmDates
        End If
    Next

    'Add formatted administred dates to derived table
    Dim o_Item As String
    For Each o_Item In o_AdmDates
        o_DerivedTable.Columns.Add(o_Item)
    Next

    'Loop through the administred date
    Dim o_NewRow As DataRow
    Dim o_NextRow As DataRow
    Dim i_Ctr As Integer
    Dim x_isNewRow As Boolean = True
    Dim i_MaxRec As Integer

    i_MaxRec = o_Dataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

    For i_Ctr = 0 To i_MaxRec
        o_Row = o_Dataset.Tables(0).Rows(i_Ctr)
        If i_Ctr <> i_MaxRec Then
            o_NextRow = o_Dataset.Tables(0).Rows(i_Ctr + 1)
        End If

        If x_isNewRow Then
            o_NewRow = o_DerivedTable.NewRow()
        End If

        o_NewRow("TransDate") = o_Row("TransDate")
        o_NewRow("Medication") = o_Row("Medication")
        o_NewRow("Dosage") = o_Row("Dosage")
        o_NewRow("TransNum") = o_Row("TransNum")

        'Fill approriate result date column based on query
        For Each o_Item In o_AdmDates
            s_FormattedAdmDate = Format(CDate(o_Row.Item("AdministeredDate")), KC_Date_Format)
            Dim AdmTim As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(o_Row("AdministeredDate"))
            If s_FormattedAdmDate = o_Item Then
                o_NewRow(s_FormattedAdmDate) = AdmTim.ToString("hh:mm tt") + " - " + o_Row("UserID")
            End If

        Next

        If i_Ctr < i_MaxRec _
            And Not o_NextRow Is Nothing _
            And o_Row("TransDate") = o_NextRow("TransDate") _
            And o_Row("Medication") = o_NextRow("Medication") _
            And o_Row("Dosage") = o_NextRow("Dosage") _
            And o_Row("AdministeredDate") = o_NextRow("AdministeredDate") Then
            x_isNewRow = False
        Else
            o_DerivedTable.Rows.Add(o_NewRow)
            x_isNewRow = True
        End If

    Next

    'Bind derived table
    dgSheet.DataSource = o_DerivedTable
    dgSheet.DataBind()

    If o_Dataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        GroupGridView(dgSheet.Items, 0, 3)
    Else

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: so is a view problem, in how you prepare data for dgv.  I think you must check : o_DerivedTable.Rows.Add(o_NewRow), to not add a new row for each Administration Date ... you must keep the same row and add colums..

Comment: pls help me recode @CristiC777

Comment: OK, first i think is better to add generic names to columns, like date1, date2, etc , and feed them with data from dataRow like  date1 = "Jan 19 2015 04:14 PM-8" ; date2 = "Jan 18 2015 04:13 PM - 8"

Comment: I still don't understand your logic .. but I guess that, you create the row here :   If s_AdmDate = o_Item Then
                o_NewRow(s_AdmDate) = AdmTim.ToString("hh:mm tt") + " - " + o_Row("UserID")
            End If                     , and I'm sure is working on a new row but in not working well when is not new, because here you need a new set of condition to add a new column, with a date ..

Comment: if i will add a new column with a date, then i will have duplicate columns but this time with a date?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must review your programming logic:
After that huge ugly SqlStr : you will have a DataSet, with a Table with all rows mixed !? 
Let's try a pseudo-code:

```
  I think is better to create in that DataSet, 2 Tables:<br>
   **first** table with: id, DateOrder, Medication, Dosage <br>
   and **second** table with: idDate, FirstTable.id, AdministeredDate
```

after that you know how many ADMMED.AdministeredDate.Count are, because you must know how manny columns you need to add

**create a 3-rd table from iteration of first table**, nested with second by ID.
*Set as Datasource for DataGridView the Third DataTable.*

Comment: gogogo    gogogo     :)

Comment: what is the id that you are referring to?

Comment: pls read again : **first** table with: id, DateOrder, Medication, Dosage <br>
   and **second** table with: idDate, FirstTable.id, AdministeredDate

Comment: you have 2 tables = Datasets , first with id, DateOrder, Medication etc and the second with table1.id, medicationDate, etc one-to-many

Comment: what do you mean by FirstTable.id?

Answer (score 0):

So you have 2 datasets, and generate this one ..  one to many ..
.. I have no time now, if you don't get the ideea .. forget it !

[image]